# Drupal TableGenerator class not working in drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-6

I've migrated a website from drupal 6 to drupal 7. I was using Druapl6/TableGenerator class. After migration this class wont work. When I call:

```
$Table = new TableGenerator();
```

it gives this error

> Error
>       The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.

Is it possible to get this working in drupal 7?
Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the parentheses: `$Table = new TableGenerator();`

However, I can't find any reference to a `TableGenerator` class in the Drupal API. If it's coming from a contrib module, make sure that module is enabled and compatible with D7.

Your best bet is to enable error reporting (remember to disable it for production environments). Stick the following in your `settings.php`:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
```

Comment: Sorry that was a typo, already using parenthesis in code. Its not a module, its a class that i used for formatting data. I've already tried error_reporting doesn't indicate any error.

Comment: The fact that you're getting the generic `The website encountered an unexpected error` means that PHP is hiding the specific error from you. Try putting those options in your `php.ini` (and restart your webserver). There's an error in there somewhere; you just need to get to it. Otherwise, debugging an issue like this is just making random guesses in the dark.